# Mysql subtraction with 2 table or php

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 table(example A and B)

A

```
-----------
id | name
-----------
1  | Bruce

2  | Peter

3  | Jack

4  | Alin
```

B

```
---------------------
id | status | A_id
---------------------
1  |    0   | 1

2  |    0   | 3
```

Subtraction with 2 table or php , I want to result is C

C

```
------------
id  | name
------------
2   | Peter
4   | Alin
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `select A.id, A.name from A,B where A.id <> B.A_id` try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give a try. Your `C` is a records that not shown from `B` right?

```
SELECT * From table a where id NOT IN (SELECT a_id from B)
```